# mysqldump limit records in between

Tags: mysql

```
mysqldump --opt --where="true LIMIT 100" dbname > dbname.sql
```

but what if I want records from row 2000 to 3000 ? 
like in general sql we can use LIMIT 2000, 3000; but is there any similar alterntative for mysqldump ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

there `--where` seems like sql injection prompt,
however is **handy**

```
mysqldump --opt --where="1 ORDER BY id LIMIT 2000, 1000" dbname > dbname.sql
```

Comment: its 1000, 2000 or 2000, 1000 ? or that doesn't matter at all ?

Comment: 1000,2000= record 1000 to 3000(2000 records).where 2000,1000=record 2000 to 3000(return 1000 records)

Comment: In SQL `LIMIT 2000 OFFSET 1000`?